# ionospheric-related vs. ionosphere-related

Tags: adjectives

I am not sure which of the following sentences is correct (or which is the "best" version):

1. [...] texts describing mainly **ionospheric-related** experiments.
2. [...] texts describing mainly **ionospheric related** experiments.
3. [...] texts describing mainly **ionospheric** experiments.
4. [...] texts describing mainly **ionosphere related** experiments.

My understanding is that 1 is better than 2 as it is a compound adjective. I am not sure though if the second adjective (*related*) is really needed in this context as *ionospheric* basically means something related to the ionosphere (please correct me if I'm wrong). Initially I was favoring 1, but currently I am not sure if not 3 (or 4) is the better choice. Any hints or comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is similar to scientific fiction or science fiction.  I will go for the latter; that is, Ionosphere-related experiments.

Comment: Compound adjectives like this are usually of the form [noun + V-ed]: grass-covered / moth-eaten / housebound / bread-related (the last from 'Red Dwarf').

Comment: If experiments involve mountains they are 'mountain experiments' : definitely not 'mountainous experiments'.

Comment: What does Wiktionary include?

Answer (score 1):

If **“ionospheric experiments”** is scientifically correct, it is the best answer as the *shortest*, *clearest* and *least ambiguous*.

By scientifically correct, I mean “do the experiments involve the ionosphere directly?”. I assume so. Only if they are *indirectly or tangentially* related to the ionosphere would “ionospheric-related” be the choice.

Let me illustrate why X-related is not the same as X.

As a biological scientist I can do experiments to find out how some biochemical sequence of reactions operates, e.g. is A converted to B and then to C?  They would be *biochemical* experiments not *cancer* experiments. But if I wish to argue (in an article or grant application) that the experiments are relevant to cancer (perhaps because the sequence of reactions is disturbed in cancer) I could refer to them as *cancer-related* experiments.

Adding *related* (and other words) when not required, devalues its meaning when it is required. And scientific thought and argument requires as much precision as possible in the use of words.

Comment: Would you expect a paper in biochemistry say to carry no attributed supporting references? And note that precision may not always be the controlling factor; 'physical' say is so polysemous that 'physics' or 'physics-related' is almost mandatory for 'relating to physics' (**physical** ... ... ... ... ... ... 4. Of or relating to matter and energy **or** the sciences dealing with them, especially physics.; [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/physical)). // Here, OP does not specify the situation clearly enough, nor his target audience. 'We can only answer if we know what the experiments....'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I think there are two kinds of support for answers. One is references to support statements. Most, if not all, of my answers in SE Biology include those, as do most in SE EL&U. However, especially here, I think that logical argument is a second and valid type of support. I think it is valid because it is falsifiable. If my argument (here illustrated by analogy) has flaws in it, someone can identify them and point them out. Although I wrote in the comment that I forgot to delete that we can only know the answer "if", my answer covers both cases.

Comment: You need to at least add a definition of 'ionospheric' from a reputable source (whether a scientific glossary or a reputable mainstream dictionary). The only one I can find that gives a reasonable definition (actually two) (Of or pertaining to the ionosphere) is Wiktionary (CED gives the broader sense). Both senses are _lexical definitions_. If you are claiming that the broader sense is an _inflationary use_ (qv) and that it must be eschewed, in favour of a _precising definition_ (qv), you are adopting a prescriptive stance. And note that the proper site for subject-specific senses is not ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I think it is evident that my answer is not intended to be subject-specific, which is why I drew an analogy from another subject which I hoped would make the meaning clearer. That is why I don't really care about ionosphere, and feel it is up to the poster to clarify this if he is interested. The aim of this site is to provide answers to questions of *general* interest or applicability ("Make it relevant to others") although admittedly this question is rather small beer.

Comment: interesting thought, and, yes, *ionospheric experiments* would then be the "correct" choice. I also realize that I should have added a bit of context since there is no clear answer to the question. Thanks for the discussion in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

*Ionospheric* means "ionosphere related," so the word *ionospheric* by itself conveys the meaning. I didn't see *ionospheric* as a separate entry in the few dictionaries I checked; it was just listed as the adjective form of *ionosphere*. For what it's worth, I also took three credits of meteorology in college.

Comment: I'd say the default meanings of 'ionospheric' are 'found in or occurring in or caused by the ionosphere'. 'Ionosphere-related' is possibly a better choice here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that sounds like a good explanation to me, together with Nigel J's comment to the question, I think "ionosphere-related" seems to be the best choice (maybe you want to add that as an answer?)

Comment: @Alf It's not that I try to avoid answers, but if I have a suggestion I think is reasonable, but can't find a reference to support it, I almost always stick to 'comments'. I feel answers here should be more than punditry.